# Dual boot grub help

Tags: grub2

I have a dual boot with Linux Mint and Ubuntu 18.04.

I need to add "GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="iommu=soft"  to /etc/default/grub
to make usb 3.0 work with my system. I have it set in mint as it was the first os I installed, but I can't get it working in Ubuntu. I can't figure out for the life of me how to make it work for both.

Comment: I ended up installing and running boot repair and everything is working fine. I'd love to know what it did, but oh well :)

Comment: Did Boot-Repair change this? cat /etc/default/grub
 And the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`